# Resizing images with sharp after streaming from google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-storage, sharp

I am trying to resize an image after streaming from google cloud storage. The streaming works fine but the resizing does not seem to work. I need to pass the image object to the resize function of sharpjs which will then resize and return the image in the API response.

My code is as below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
let server = express()
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = '<some-bucket-name>'

    server.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {
      // Extract the query-parameter
      const widthString = req.query.width
      const heightString = req.query.height
      const format = req.query.format
      const fileName = req.path.substring(1);
      console.log("url: ", req.path)
      // Parse to integer if possible
      let width, height
      if (widthString) {
        width = parseInt(widthString)
      }
      if (heightString) {
        height = parseInt(heightString)
      }
      // Set the content-type of the response
      res.type(`image/${format || 'png'}`)
    
      // Get the resized image
          downloadFileStream(fileName).then((imageObj) =>{
            resize(imageObj, format, width, height).pipe(res)
          })
          .catch ((e) =>
            console.log(e)
          );
    })
    
    async function downloadFileStream(fileName){
           return await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).createReadStream().pipe()
    }
```

I am missing something in the way i should be calling resize after the file download. I get following error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at PassThrough.Readable.pipe (internal/streams/readable.js:657:8)
    at streamFile (/home/adityam/imageoptimizer/server.js:40:82)
    at /home/adityam/imageoptimizer/server.js:30:7
```

Comment: Looking at this code ... return await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).createReadStream().pipe()   I'm not getting the "await" ... surely await takes a "Promise" and blocks until the promise is resolved.   Looking at the docs, I'm not seeing that "pipe()" returns a Promise?    Which source statement is throwing the exception?

Comment: ```return await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).createReadStream().pipe()``` This is the line at which error is generated. In the source docs @https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/HEAD/samples/streamFileDownload.js seems to take a filestream. When i skip resize() and pass resp directly then it works fine.

Comment: I think you're missing the bucket name in your function `download File Stream` since the variable `bucketName` is used but not defined (although you have it defined globally somewhere else in your code)

Comment: @RogelioMonter bucketName was globaly defined(I have updated the details). So this is not the issue. Issue was about how to call resize() on the file stream generated by downloadFile.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-process-images-in-node-js-with-sharp) and [this](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#resize) tutorials, I would suggest rewriting your resize function in this way:

*include sharp library*

```js
const sharp =  require("sharp");
```

*get image using `downloadFileStream` function, then resize*

```js
const image = downloadFileStream(fileName)
const resized = await sharp(image)
    .resize({
        width: width,
        height: height
    })
    .toBuffer()
    .then( data => {
        //...
    })
```

See also:

- https://github.com/lovell/sharp